# Battery care if I don't plan to use my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Let's say I plan not to use my rMBP for a few days (5-7), is there anything special I should do in order to keep the battery in good condition?

Answer (score 4):

No. 5-7 days is way less than an extended period of time @FoamyBeer refers to. Imagine that a lot of devices stay in warehouses longer than the time you want not to use your MBP. Just handle it as if it was a book:

- Don't drop it
- Neither heat nor freeze it
- Keep it dry

In addition to that, do *NOT* leave it with a discharged battery. Actually, it's no big deal to have it connected to the charger the whole time. If your going on vacation, disconnect it from the charger to prevent damages by lightning strikes.

Comment: +1 for saying it's no big deal to leave it connected to the charger the whole time.  So many that assume Apple engineers gave no thought to starting and stopping the charge.   I'm surprised someone doesn't suggest wrapping the device in tin foil "to stabilize the battery".

Comment: To convince people about charging circuits preventing overcharging a battery, just show them this video and ask them how often they've seen this happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixIOEPnsgbI

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's advice](http://www.apple.com/uk/batteries/maximizing-performance/) if you're storing a device for extended period of time, is:

- do not fully charge or fully discharge your battery, but charge it around 50%
- Power down the device
- Place in a cool moisture-free environment that's less than 32° C (90° F)